# SSH Private Key Not Working After Fetching It From Google's Secret Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-secret-manager

I have an SSH Private Key which I use to SSH into some server. I have tested the key and it works perfectly. I have uploaded the key to Google Cloud Secret Manager, but when I fetch it from the Secret Manager using the *gcloud secrets versions access* command, the key does not work and this error is returned instead:

```
Load key "id_rsa": invalid format
```

Is there a way I can get the key while preserving its format? Or can I reformat the key?

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried getting the key in using different formats;

```
gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=${SECRET} --format="json" | jq -r .payload.data | base64 --decode > id_rsa

gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=${SECRET} --format='get(payload.data)' | tr '_-' '/+' | base64 -d > id_rsa
```

But it has not worked.

Comment: Does `gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="${SECRET}"` not work? That should return the plaintext. Have you inspected the result to see if it's a properly-formatted key? How did you create the secret in Secret Manager to begin with?

Comment: The results seem fine to me, but ssh is complaining that it is not formatted correctly. I created the secret by copying the SSH private key contents and pasting them in the value box.

Comment: Have you compared the contents of `id_rsa` on disk with the expected results? Do they appear to match?

Comment: Create a disposable test key. Repeat and show the source and the returned key in your question.

Comment: Also show the command that is storing the key.

Comment: Yes @sethvargo, I have compared the contents, and they match.

Comment: Sorry friends, I did not have an empty line at the end, that is why I was getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I had a similar situation, in my case it was an empty line at the end missing.